# Snowflake latteral flatten data types

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

I have a table containing an id column and a json column(variant data type). I want to flatten the data, make the `value` column a `variant`, assign each value in the `value` column a data type if a condition is met, then eventually pivot the data and have each column be the correct data type.

Example code that doesn't work:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        1 as id,
        parse_json('{
            "field1":"TRUE",
            "field2":"some string",
            "field3":"1.035",
            "field4":"097334"
        }') as my_output
)

select 
    id,
    key,
    to_variant(
        case
            when value in ('true', 'false') then value::boolean
            when value like ('1.0') then value::decimal
            else value::string
        end) as value
from cte, lateral flatten(my_output)
```

Ultimately, I'd like to pivot the data and have a wide table with columns `id`, `field1`, `field2`, etc. where `field1` is `boolean`, `field2` is `string`, `field3` is a `decimal` etc.

This is just a simple example, instead of 4 fields, I'm dealing with hundreds.
Is this possible?

For the pivot, I'm using `dbt_utils.get_column_values` to get the column names dynamically. I'd really prefer a solution that doesn't involve listing out the column names, especially since there are hundreds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution ended up being

```
select
    id,
    key,
    ifnull(try_parse_json(value), value) as value_mod,
    typeof(value_mod)
from cte, lateral flatten(my_output)
```

Leading zeros are removed so things like zip codes have to be accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you'd have to define each column in your `PIVOT` statement, anyway, it'd probably be much easier to simply select each attribute directly and cast to the correct data type, rather than using a lateral flatten.

```
select
    my_output.field1::boolean,
    my_output.field2::string,
    my_output.field3::decimal(5,3),
    my_output.field4::string
from cte;
```

Alternatively, if you want this to be dynamically created, you could create a stored procedure that dynamically uses your json to create a view over your table that has this select in it.

Comment: `you could create a stored procedure that dynamically uses your json to create a view over your table` Already done: https://github.com/GregPavlik/InferSchema. There are a couple of SPs in that project. `create_view_over_variant` does what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for this Greg. I updated my question to include that I'm using `dbt_utils.get_column_values` to get the column names dynamically, so I'd really prefer a solution that doesn't involve listing out the names, if possible. I also don't have permissions for stored procedures.